# How to select files that don't contain a certain string in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, string-comparison

I have a directory with 10000 files. I want to select those files for processing that don't contain the string "_B". There are other files with the character B that I don't want to exclude.

I tried to do the following:

```
for k=1:n
    if(~contains(files(k).name, '*_B*.png'))
    ...
end
```

But this just selects all the files with "_B" instead. If I remove the tilde in front of "contains", none of the files are getting selected. What do I change the line into to get the desired results?

Comment: [`strcmp`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) might help you instead.

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern string be `_B` rather than `'*_B*.png'`?

Comment: @adriaan Isn't strcmp going to be restrictive? I mean, if I have a file named "001_B.c", and I use strcmp(filename, _B), they aren't gonna match right? So I tried "strfind" but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: @luis mendo What you've suggested will apply to a single file named _B.png I assume, not to files that "contain" the string, for example, it might fail on a file named 00_B.png.

Comment: The `contains` function will, as the name suggests, return true for any string containing the pattern string. So just using `_B` will return true for `_B.png` and also `123_B.png` or `anytexthere_Bah.whatever`. The wildcards might actually be causing the issue

Comment: @etmuse Thank you, it's working now. Could you post it as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcards in your pattern statement are likely the cause of the problem; [`contains`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) doesn't need them. As the name of the function suggests, it will return true if the string 'contains' the pattern string, whatever else is around it.

So 
`contains(files(k).name, '_B')` will return true for `_B.png` or `123_B.png` or `randomfilename_Bahaha.whatever`

Thus the only change you need to make to your existing code is to remove the wildcards from your pattern string and just leave `'_B'`

Answer (score 1):

As @Adriaan has mentioned is his comment, you can use [strcmp](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) which compares strings. In your case you want to do something like that:

```
for k=1:n
    if strcmp(files(k).name,'_B') %compare your filename with '_B', strcmp returns 1 if it finds the string '_B' in it, 0 otherwise
    %process _B files
    end
end
```

Comment: Are s1 and filename one and the same? Can you please explain the code with comments, I'm not able to grasp it.

Comment: MATLAB ~= C++; comments work different in MATLAB. (i.e. not with slashes)

Comment: @Matte I edited my answer, it's pretty straight forward. Thanks @Adriaan!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid for loops by applying cell functions. First list the files. Here I list all files ending with '.png'. Then see which ones contain the string '_B', then choose filenames without it.

```
DIR=dir('*.png');
fName={DIR(:).name}';
searchResult=cellfun(@findstr,fName,repmat({'_B'},length(fName),1),'UniformOutput',false);
chosen=fName(cellfun(@isempty,searchResult));
```